# How to avoid nested if statements in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Is there a way to refactor this in Elixir to make it more readable?

```
  def validate(params) do
    Repo.start_link

    if validate_oauth_params(params) === true do
      oauth_client = Repo.get_by(OauthClient, random_id: params["client_id"], secret: params["secret"])

      if oauth_client != nil do
        allowed_grant_types = Poison.Parser.parse!(oauth_client.allowed_grant_types)
        if Map.has_key?(allowed_grant_types, params["grant_type"]) do
          case params["grant_type"] do
            "password" ->
              process_password_grant(params, oauth_client)
            "refresh_token" ->
              process_refresh_token_grant(params["refresh_token"], oauth_client)
            "client_credentials" ->
              process_client_credentials_grant(oauth_client)
            nil ->
              %{message: "Invalid oauth credentials", code: 400}
          end
        end
      else
        %{message: "Invalid oauth credentials", code: 400}
      end
    else
      %{message: "Invalid oauth credentials", code: 400}
    end
  end
```

What is the Elixir way of doing it because this code looks like PHP. I did not write it.

Comment: Decompose the code into subfunctions. I don't have time right now to re-write that code but abstract the innermost `if` into a separate function and maybe do likewise with the other `if`'s

Comment: your developer should take this awesome getting started guide, to understand at least the key points: http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/introduction.html

Comment: It seems this question would be more at home at the Code Review exchange

Comment: How to move it there? Hope there is a way. Sorry bout this. I thought there are more lurkers here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, it looks like PHP. The benefits of elixir like pattern matching are not used.

It's difficult to refactor this one piece, because it seems that the other methods should also be refactored, to do it more clean. For example the `validate_oauth_params` function "could" return a tuple instead of a boolean value, so you would pattern match against it, and you would be done like:

```
def validate(params) do
  case validate_oauth_params(params) do
    {:ok, params} -> choose_oauth_method params
    {:error} -> handle_error "Invalid params"
  end
end

defp choose_oauth_method(%{"grant_type" => "password"} = params) do
  process_password_grant(params)
end
defp choose_oauth_method(%{"grant_type" => nil}) do
  handle_error "Method undefined"
end

defp handle_error(msg), do: %{message: msg, code: 400}
defp handle_error(msg, code), do: %{message: msg, code: code}
defp handle_error(), do: %{message: "Default error massage", code: 400}
```

something like this, this is not working code at all, just to give an idea, how pattern matching works and its benefits

Comment: Your last `handle_error` clause won't ever match. It's equivalent to the first one, but just ignores the parameter. Did you intend for it to be simply `handle_error()` -- with no parameter?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to rewrite this code using `with` expression to something like

```
def validate(params) do
  with
    {:ok, p} <- validate_oauth_params(params),
    {:ok, client} = get_client_for_params(p),
    {:ok, allowed_grant_types} <- Poison.Parser.parse(oauth_client.allowed_grant_types)
  do
    case params["grant_type"] do
      "password" ->
        process_password_grant(params, oauth_client)
      "refresh_token" ->
        process_refresh_token_grant(params["refresh_token"], oauth_client)
      "client_credentials" ->
        process_client_credentials_grant(oauth_client)
      nil -> :error
    end
  end |> case do
    {:ok, something} -> something
    _ -> %{message: "Invalid oauth credentials", code: 400}
  end
end
```

However such a refactiong may require more changes in other code or introduction of helper functions to return recognizable values and errors. `with` currently does not support guards in patterns, but it will in 1.3.

Comment: Looks more organized but still a mess IMHO.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a bit of a different approach I like to use when logic gets really complex and a with/do statement is not enough.

```
def validate(params) do
    try do
        if !validate_oauth_params(params), do: 
            throw({:error, %{message: "Invalid oauth credentials", code: 400}})

        if !oauth_client, do: 
            throw({:error, %{message: "Invalid oauth credentials", code: 400}})

        allowed_grant_types = Poison.Parser.parse!(oauth_client.allowed_grant_types)
        if !Map.has_key?(allowed_grant_types, params["grant_type"]), do:
            throw({:error, %{message: "No grant type", code: 400}})

        case params["grant_type"] do
            "password" ->
                process_password_grant(params, oauth_client)
            "refresh_token" ->
                process_refresh_token_grant(params["refresh_token"], oauth_client)
            "client_credentials" ->
                process_client_credentials_grant(oauth_client)
            nil ->
                throw({:error, %{message: "Invalid oauth credentials", code: 400}})
        end
    catch
        {:error, map} -> {:error, map}
    else
        result -> {:ok, result}
    end
end
```